# Sublime Text 3: language specific custom syntax highlighting

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a default theme set up. But I want some changes to syntax highlighting for only Python files. How should I do it in ST3?

Comment: If you're willing to try a different theme, [I made one](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-sublime-theme) that's optimized for Python, as well as a bunch of other languages. It takes advantage of pretty much every scope available in the Python language definition.

Comment: Thanks for that theme -- I'll modify it and make it light!

Comment: no problem. If you fork it on github, could you send me a link? Thanks!